# Sum of all positive integers : $\sqrt{7p^n+9}$

Tags: number-theory

Find the sum of all positive integers which can be expressed as $\sqrt{7p^n+9}$ for some positive integer $n$ and some prime number $p$.

Official answer 49, my answer 10+11+24=45. Is it wrong ?

Comment: Indeed, $45\ne49$.

Comment: I think they have also added $\sqrt {7 (1)^n +9} =4$, but clearly $1$ is not prime.

Comment: @ Rohan, I think so. Thank you both.

Comment: I think, they knew that $p=1$ was not prime, and included $n=0$ (for some "non-negative integer", instead of "positive" integer).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, you're right. Thank you.